# Different appearance of interface in xml layout when run in AVD/Graphical Layout

Tags: android, xml

I'm working on Android. This is what my AVD looks like when I run it. Why  is it different than in the xml layout?
How can I make it look the same?

[image: And this is my xml layout look like,]

[image: And this is AVD look like]

Comment: Check your Graphical layout with different device size by changing device from device tab..

Comment: it is same xml layout, looking different due to difference in resolution and screen size of emulators. For consistency, you have to create different xmls for different resolutions and place them in appropriate folders( eg: layout-large)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to create different layout to support all screen size in android.

Standard Screen sizes as per developer docs is

- xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
- large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
- normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
- small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

You should read [Supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

More about screen resolutions in android visit below links.

[**android multi-screen support 1**](http://stefan222devel.blogspot.in/2012/10/android-screen-densities-sizes.html)

[**android multi-screen support 2**](https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/screen-layout.html)